# iPhone app Debug Is very fast but (Adhoc and appstore) Release is very slow

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, performance

Does anyone know of any potential causes of chuggy slowness through out an iPhone app, as a result of some kind of config or third party library in the release version of an app?

I have libTestFlight, libGoogleAnalytics, libBlitFeedback, MKNetwork as well as Bolts, NewRelic, Parse and the Facebook SDK... everything else is a standard iOS SDK library.

When I build for Debug, she runs lightning fast... I simply change to 'archive' and release the app on test flight and walah it runs like a piece of crap.

I use images heavily which are all generally loaded by using "UIImageView+WebCache.h" and the SDWebImage package https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

I'm just in the process of elimation at the moment as the app never used to run chuggy, but I made a lot of changes in the space of a week which were all intended to make the app smoother and faster.

An example use case is:

1. User opens App.
2. Table View loads cells with images and text.
3. Network call updates data.
4. User taps tab bar to change to a UICollectionViewController. It reloads.
5. User taps Profile VC, it refreshes some data.

In Debug... this use case is lightnining fast, transitions smooth and quick on iPhone 4 or 5

In Release mode.. Tapping on the tab bar takes 3 seconds to transition. Scrolling is clunky in the tableview or collection view.

Comment: not enough information to diagnose. which part is slow?

Comment: An example use case is:

User opens App.
Table View loads cells with images and text.
Network call updates data.
User taps tab bar to change to a UICollectionViewController. It reloads.
User taps Profile VC, it refreshes some data.
In Debug... this use case is lightnining fast, transitions smooth and quick on iPhone 4 or 5

In Release mode.. Tapping on the tab bar takes 3 seconds to transition. Scrolling is clunky in the tableview or collection view.

Comment: Making request to same URL ? Suggest to review Device Console Log in Xcode Organizer > Devices > Your Device > Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, the reason was the result of dropping this particular piece of code in my release target.

https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345

And more precisely this piece of code #define PROPERTY(propName) @#propName:

// Compile-time selector checks.

## if DEBUG

## define PROPERTY(propName) NSStringFromSelector(@selector(propName))

## else

## define PROPERTY(propName) @#propName

## endif

Was found to be the cause of our problems only discovered by using profiler and realising that it was just soaking up the available CPU cycles. iPhone 4 was so slow it basically was unresponsive.

Anyway, the generic answer is to profile your app to see whats slowing the CPU down.